# Selecting a text area with jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm using a jQuery script (called 'dotdotdot') to select RSS-sourced text and truncate it to the size of a div. Unfortunately, I can't seem to figure out the ID of the element I should select, so the script isn't truncating anything.

Here's the script I'm using:

```
<!-- rss truncator -->
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="custom_js/jquery.dotdotdot.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".i908miniblogmetadataclassblog").dotdotdot();
});
</script>
```

It's currently active on http://tinychivalry.com/cjyoga/

I'm trying to point it at the blog description section - I've tried quite a few IDs, but nothing has worked. No errors are being generated by Firebug to imply the script is broken, so my assumption is either:

- I am pointing the script at the wrong place
- My script won't work with the RSS feed data I am pulling.

Hopefully it's not the latter, but even if it is, I really look forward to getting some additional insight on selecting tricky elements like this.

Thank you!!

edit: I've also tried #miniblog #miniblogpanel, and variations thereof, which haven't worked.

Comment: Are you loading the RSS data using AJAX? If so, you can't run `dotdotdot` until after the data is loaded.

Comment: It should be a separate javascript call ("function processXML") pulling the RSS data under 'var dataurl'.  Would the same still apply?  If so, is there a way for dotdotdot to live in the header and still truncate the data (like adding a document.ready modification)?

Comment: That sounds like AJAX. You should be able to provide a callback function that's run when the data is loaded, and that function should call `dotdotdot`.